# Merging metronic code with angular-seed-advanced

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular-seed-advanced

I have replaced index.html file of metronic with the index.html file of angular-seed-advanced (`src/client`) also I have dropped my metronic code inside the client folder but after running the code I am “Parser blocking cross site error”.

Can you please check our Metronic code (angular) which needs to be merged in angular-seed-advanced.

Below is my git url by which you can check my angular code of Metronic and also I am sharing  documentation of Metronic.

One more question, can we please use Angular 4 in angular-seed-advanced.

Metronic code git: https://github.com/Jeremywhiteley/MedTexterNative/tree/11-10-2017/angular

Metronic Documentation: http://keenthemes.com/metronic/documentation.html

Snapshot of error: https://screencast.com/t/aPPFvlsJnr6

Comment: 1. Who is Nathan? 2. SO doesn't do *"asap"*, this isn't a helpdesk. 3. If you have a problem you would like help solving, give a [mcve] **in the question**. Please spend some time in the [help].

Comment: im assuming Nathan Walker, perhaps this should have been sent to him in the nativescript slack channel?

Comment: Since this question is not self-contained, it is off-topic. If you can add the necessary code to the question, it will be on-topic.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.